# hiddenDOMWindow failed after browser restart

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fennec

This code works correct after installation extention, 
but when I restart browser it fails.
What is the difference of calling startup function :

on install

on start

code:

```
function startup(aData, aReason) {
_webSocket = new Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.WebSocket("ws://localhost:8887/");
...
}
```

error:
 [JavaScript Warning: "WARN addons.xpi: Exception running bootstrap method startup on screen-capture@smail.com: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIAppShellService.hiddenDOMWindow]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/files/mozilla/lmwz0qwc.default/extensions/screen-capture@smail.com.xpi!/bootstrap.js :: SmartScreencap.connect_ws :: line 89"  data: no]" {file: "resource://gre/modules/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/files/mozilla/lmwz0qwc.default/extensions/screen-capture@smail.com.xpi!/bootstrap.js" line: 89}]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow is not created when `function startup(aData, aReason)` is colling. So the solution is to add window listener into startup function
 `win.addEventListener('UIReady', function() {
      ...
         Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.WebSocket//call function here
      ...
    }, false);`
and call hidden window from callback function.